# What does it mean when multiple 々 marks follow a 、?

Tags: punctuation, symbols, kanbun

I was glancing at some old manuscripts from the Heian period ([左経記 pg. 10](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/949547)) when I saw the following:
[image: 左経記 pg. 10]

I know that typically 々 means to repeat the previous kanji, but what does it mean when its following a 、? Also, is there a reason there are so many of them in a row like in 々々々應召?

Comment: Wild guess, the two in a row stand for 巳及, and the three in row stand for 令召右.

Comment: This is not really Classical Japanese, it's Kanbun（漢文）, which is really just Classical Chinese（文言文）

Comment: The「、」is just a generic pause mark - notice how there's no「。」in the entire book, which means「、」would be rendered as either「、」or「。」in a more modern orthography. Also @sazarando JSE doesn't seem to have a tag for `kanbun` hmm...

Comment: The forward（part of the 標題 section）is in Classical Japanese though...

Comment: Making a new tag for [tag:kanbun] makes sense.  I wouldn't say kanbun is "just" Classical Chinese, though.

Comment: @Ringil Are you doing research about 天皇の譲位？

Comment: @snailboat Yes, sorry about that. I should have said "which is a form of" Classical Chinese.

Comment: @sazarando I'm not sure this is what would typically called Classical Chinese... Also, no, I'm not researching anything specifically. I just happened upon this thing and couldn't really figure it out despite knowing a bit of Classical Chinese. But while doing that I noticed many weird things about the punctuation.

Comment: I suppose I should have just created the tag kanbun instead of using classical Japanese, which I used because of the time period.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

「々」is called「同{どう}の字{じ}点{てん}」it is used to repeat 1 previous character.

> 人**人**　=　人**々**

When there are multiple 同の字点 it means to repeat *'n'* previous characters.

> - 已及深更、**深更**後... =
> - 已及深更、**々々**後...

&

> - 令召右大辨、**右大辨**應召 =
> - 令召右大辨、**々々々**應召